# Is it a security risk if someone knows a salesforce account id?

Tags: salesforce

I'm 90% sure that the answer is no but I would appreciate your thoughts.

Scenario:  We build a system that uses Salesforce record IDs to locate information.  This system is now shared with people outside our company thereby sharing record IDs.  (It goes without saying that we do not expose our instance ID nor any credentials of authentic users within our organization.   The only type of information that is visible is the record id.)

Is there anyway a malicious person could use the record ID and cause damage: either reading the data or worse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so. Even if someone gets your instance ID, the only thing he could do is to spam your system (and may be make you out of API calls), but nothing more. Revealing of record ids is just okay.